# Sending keypresses to a game, it doesn't work for arrow buttons

Tags: python, keyboard, ctypes, directinput

I'm trying to send keyboard inputs to a game, and after a lot of search I finally found a code that works:

```
# http://www.gamespp.com/directx/directInputKeyboardScanCodes.html

import ctypes
import time

SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput

W = 0x11
A = 0x1E
S = 0x1F
D = 0x20
Z = 0x2C
X = 0x2D
Q = 0x10
UP = 0xC8
DOWN = 0xD0
LEFT = 0xCB
RIGHT = 0xCD
ENTER = 0x1C 

# C struct redefinitions 
PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)
class KeyBdInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
                ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)]

class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
                ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time",ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("ki", KeyBdInput),
                 ("mi", MouseInput),
                 ("hi", HardwareInput)]

class Input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("ii", Input_I)]

# Actuals Functions

def pressKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def releaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008 | 0x0002, 0, 
ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pressKey(0x11)
    time.sleep(1)
    releaseKey(0x11)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Here's how I adapted it in my program:

```
def press(key):
    num = KEYS[key] # Global dict which makes a mapping
                    # Of "W" to 0x11 for example
    pressKey(num)
    time.sleep(1)       
    releaseKey(num)
```

While it does work for letters such as "Z, X, W, B, etc.." It doesn't seem to work for arrows (UP - DOWN - LEFT - RIGHT). The arrows do work in notepad but they do not work in the game. How can I modify this code so that it can work for arrow buttons as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Numpad has arrow keys on 4, 6, 8, and 2. It's pressing those. Turn off Numpad Lock on your keyboard. I had the same issue and I feel pretty stupid now.